# how to do a left join with no duplicate columns?

Tags: sql

I have to join 2 tables and the first table I'm joining consists of:

```
Physicians (ID, FirstName, LastName, PracticeID, SpecialtyID, Email)
```

and the second table I have is:

```
PhysicianSpecialties( SpecialtyID, SpecialtyName)
```

I wrote this query to join the tables together

```
Select *
from physicians
right join PhysicianSpecialities
on PhysicianSpecialities.SpecialtyID = Physicians.SpecialtyID
```

and when I left Join them the table is now

```
(ID, FirstName, LastName, PracticeID, SpecialtyID, Email, SpecialtyID, SpecialtyName)
```

how can I rewrite this so there is only one "SpecialtyID" Column?

Comment: You have to replace the `SELECT *` with named columns.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  as tabular text

Comment: @samramos . . . A `right join` does not seem correct here.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the DBMS product you are using, but: in standard SQL you can join with the `USING` operator if the join columns have the same name in both tables.

In this case, the "duplicated" column will automatically be removed from the result.

```sql
Select *
from physicians
  right join PhysicianSpecialities using (SpecialtyID)
```

Not all DBMS products support that though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the column names of both tables instead of (`*`)

```
Select a.*,b.SpecialtyName
from physicians a
right join PhysicianSpecialities b
on b.SpecialtyID = a.SpecialtyID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT 
    physicians.ID, physicians.FirstName, physicians.LastName, 
    physicians.PracticeID, physicians.SpecialtyID, physicians.Email, 
    PhysicianSpecialities.SpecialtyName
```

instead of `SELECT *`, hence your query goes like:

```
SELECT 
    physicians.ID, physicians.FirstName, physicians.LastName, 
    physicians.PracticeID, physicians.SpecialtyID, physicians.Email, 
    PhysicianSpecialities.SpecialtyName
FROM
    physicians
LEFT JOIN 
    PhysicianSpecialities ON Physicians.SpecialtyID = PhysicianSpecialities.SpecialtyID;
```

I hope it will return the desired result.